# initializing all positions in mutlidimensional array?

Tags: c++, arrays

I can't really use a vector for this so I'm stuck with an array im having difficulty using..

```
string whitelist[256][1];
fill_n(whitelist, sizeof whitelist / sizeof **whitelist, "NULL");
```

I have also tried memset but it doesn't work in the sense that it wants an int and not a string, I have also tried

```
whitelist[256][1] = {{0}};
```

however I do not believe it worked...I don't care if 0, 1 is initialized but I need it to initiliaze the 256...

ALTERNATIVELY, I need to check if there's a value inside of whitelist[200] even if it's uninitialized, I would prefer this but from my research it cannot be done to check if it's NULL/empty.

Comment: Why can't you use a `std::vector`?

Comment: If array size is small, then iterate through all position and assign can't be bad idea.

Comment: may std::array<> be used?

Comment: Er.. What exactly is this question about? `string whitelist[256][1];` will already initialize each array element using the default constructor of `std::string`. No need to do anything extra. If this is not what you need then why did you accept the answer that does the same thing?

Comment: You cannot have "uninitialized" `std::string` object, unless you just through some serious hoops. The language will initialize your strings for you automatically.

Comment: @AnT You made me curios. How can you have an un-initialized `std::string`? Even with a no-op allocator it will still be "initialized", and even in a union to switch the member you'd need to placement-new it. Is there any actual scenario where the string can be in some un-defined state? Are you thinking of a moved-from object? But even that will be in a valid state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, for an array of type `T arr[M][N]`, you can do either:

```
T arr[M][N]{}; // C++11 or later
```

which will [value-initialize](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) the whole 2-D array with the default constructor, or, similarly for C++98,

```
 T arr[M][N] = {}; // C++98
```

However, in your case the type `std::string` provides a default constructor, then the definition

```
string whitelist[256][1];
```

uses that default constructor for every element, so each element in the array has a determinate value (i.e. the empty string), hence you can safely use them. This is of course in strike contrast to POD types, for which the value is indeterminate and you **need** to use `{}` to zero them.

Note that you can even you use something like

```
string whitelist[256][1] = {"first", "second"};
```

and the rest of the elements will be default-constructed.

Small example to convince yourself:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
    Foo(int) {std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;}
    Foo() {std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;}
};

int main()
{
    Foo arr[2][3] = {1,2}; // calls the int ctor 2 times, default ctor 4 times, as expected
    (void)arr; // to remove warning of non-used variable
}
```

[<kbd>Live on Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/329d390545527511)

Comment: What would be the point of explicitly using `{}` initilizer when a mere `string whitelist[256][1];` will automatically do the same thing? What point is this answer trying to make? What does the explicit `{}` achieve exactly?

Comment: @AnT You read my mind. I was just finishing the edit. I edited the answer accordingly now, so it makes a clear distinction between PODs and default-constructible types.

Answer (score 0):

An array declaration with `std::string` elements, like

```
string whitelist[256][1];
```

will already automatically initialize each array element using `std::string`'s default constructor (which creates an empty string). There no need to do anything.

Your apparent belief that without extra effort you'll somehow end up with "uninitialized" strings has no basis in reality.